# What kind of compounds are very basic and mildly volatile at room conditions?

Tags: acid-base

We have a liquid seeping up into our concrete.  It is dissolving our epoxy floors and we can't stop it with any sort of sealant.

I tested it with pH strips and it seems to be very basic.  It's likely not got much water content either because it evaporates fairly quickly on a mild day.

What am I dealing with here?  I am going to send it out to get tested, but I was wondering if any chemists could help me out with classifying it.

Comment: You are dealing with water which has washed out some remaining alkali from concrete.